# from external host, i cant access to my apache web server that running on vmware [centos 7 64bit]

Tags: apache-2.2, centos7

after i switched off iptables and firewalls, it doesn't work

root  ~ # service iptables status

Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  iptables.service

iptables.service - IPv4 firewall with iptables

Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iptables.service; enabled)

Active: inactive (dead)

---

service firewalld status

Redirecting to /bin/systemctl status  firewalld.service

firewalld.service - firewalld - dynamic firewall daemon

Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/firewalld.service; enabled)

Active: inactive (dead)

---

apache seems to receive syn packet from external host(windows 7 64bit) but i cant access(it works fine on local)

tcpdump -i ens33 -n src host 58.123.21.250 and port 80

tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode

listening on ens33, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes

21:47:25.112649 IP 58.123.21.250.51270 > 58.123.170.183.http: Flags [S], seq 3082818409, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 2,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0

21:47:28.112473 IP 58.123.21.250.51270 > 58.123.170.183.http: Flags [S], seq 3082818409, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 2,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0

21:47:34.124897 IP 58.123.21.250.51270 > 58.123.170.183.http: Flags [S], seq 3082818409, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0

21:47:43.580902 IP 58.123.21.250.51267 > 190.93.247.183.http: Flags [P.], seq 26863706:26864354, ack 3431357454, win 16324, length 648

21:47:43.811453 IP 58.123.21.250.51267 > 190.93.247.183.http: Flags [.], ack 405, win 16223, length 0
^C

5 packets captured

11 packets received by filter

0 packets dropped by kernel

how can i solve this problem? please help me thanks.

-------------------------- here's my output of netstat -lnp and iptables -L

root  ~ # netstat -lnp

Active Internet connections (only servers)

Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      2409/master

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:41792           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1874/rpc.statd

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1845/rpcbind

tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1496/sshd

tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3044/cupsd

tcp6       0      0 ::1:25                  :::*                    LISTEN      2409/master

tcp6       0      0 :::49065                :::*                    LISTEN      1874/rpc.statd

tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1845/rpcbind

tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1399/httpd

tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN      1496/sshd

tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      3044/cupsd

udp     2176      0 0.0.0.0:68              0.0.0.0:*                           2331/dhclient

udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:50255           0.0.0.0:*                           2331/dhclient

udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*                           1845/rpcbind

udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:123             0.0.0.0:*                           735/chronyd

udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:48774           0.0.0.0:*                           709/avahi-daemon: r

udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:53928           0.0.0.0:*                           1874/rpc.statd

udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:723             0.0.0.0:*                           1845/rpcbind

udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5353            0.0.0.0:*                           709/avahi-daemon: r

udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:778           0.0.0.0:*                           1874/rpc.statd

udp        0      0 127.0.0.1:323           0.0.0.0:*                           735/chronyd

udp6       0      0 :::46135                :::*                                1874/rpc.statd

udp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                                1845/rpcbind

udp6       0      0 :::4729                 :::*                                2331/dhclient

udp6       0      0 :::123                  :::*                                735/chronyd

udp6       0      0 :::723                  :::*                                1845/rpcbind

udp6       0      0 ::1:323                 :::*                                735/chronyd

raw6       0      0 :::58                   :::*                    7           905/NetworkManager

---

root  ~ # iptables -L

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)

target     prot opt source               destination

Comment: What's the output of `netstat -lnp`? What about `iptables -L`?

Comment: i added the output of netstat -lnp and iptables -L please check up thanks.

Comment: why this got -2 votes? please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the `netstat` output above, Apache isn't listening on an IPv4 address, but only the IPv6 ones.

There's directions [here](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ipv6-apache-configuration-tutorial/) on how to setup Apache to listen on both IPv4 and IPv6.

It might be as simple as adding a `Listen 80` directive to *httpd.conf* and restarting httpd.